# How to filter using grep on a selected word

Tags: grep

```
grep (GNU grep) 2.14
```

Hello,

I have a log file that I want to filter on a selected word. However, it tends to filter on many for example.

```
tail -f gateway-* | grep "P_SIP:N_iptB1T1"
```

This will also find words like this:

```
"P_SIP:N_iptB1T10"
"P_SIP:N_iptB1T11"
"P_SIP:N_iptB1T12"
etc
```

However, I don't want to display anything after the 1. grep is picking up 11, 12, 13, etc.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can restrict the word to end at 1:

```
tail -f gateway-* | grep "P_SIP:N_iptB1T1\>"
```

This will work assuming that you have a matching case which is only "P_SIP:N_iptB1T1".
But if you want to extract from P_SIP:N_iptB1T1x, and display only once, then you need to restrict to show only first match.

Answer (score 1):

```sh
grep -o "P_SIP:N_iptB1T1"
```

```
 -o, --only-matching       show only the part of a line matching PATTERN
```

[More info](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep)

Comment: That works ok. However, I want to display the complete line that contains that pattern, not just the pattern itself. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

At least two approaches can be tried:

`grep -w pattern` matches for full words. Seems to work for this case too, even though the pattern has punctuation.

`grep pattern -m 1` to restrict the output to first match. (Also doable with `grep xxx | head -1`)

Answer (score 1):

If the lines contains the quotes as in your example, just use the `-E` option in grep and match the closing quote with `\"`. For example:

```
grep -E "P_SIP:N_iptB1T1\"" file
```

If these quotes aren't in the text file, and there's blank spaces or endlines after the word, you can match these too:

```
# The word is followed by one or more blanks
grep -E "P_SIP:N_iptB1T1\s+" file

# Match lines ending with the interesting word
grep -E "P_SIP:N_iptB1T1$" file
```